# Accessing Grafana interface from k8s cluster with private endpoint from my windows desktop

Tags: linux, windows, kubernetes, grafana, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am running a private OKE cluster with a private endpoint. We also have Grafana running on this cluster.

In order to access the k8s private endpoint, we create a bastion session in OCI and access the k8s private endpoint from a vm instance with a public IP.

One of the requirement is to access the Grafana interface from my windows desktop machine. For this we used the below command to port fordward the grafana port to the VM instance.

```
kubectl --namespace monitoring port-forward svc/grafana 9090:3000
```

I have verified that the port 9090 is now available on the vm instance which is having a public IP.

Now I need to access this Grafana interface from my desktop machine. One option seems is to use the public IP of the vm instance and can access it from `http://<VM public IP>:9090`

But instead of exposing the VM instance IP and port 9090, can we use port forwarding to access the Grafana interface using something like `http://127.0.0.1:9000` from my desktop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you rdp into the bastion, are you able to access Grafana? If that works, then your suggestion should work.

Comment: The bastion host is a Linux host and my desktop machine is a windows machine

Comment: Same thing...if you can ssh into your bastion and from the terminal, you can issue a success curl command to your grafana dashboard, then your suggestion should work.